# Bypass SSL in local network for Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have two websites installed in the same server under IIS 10, One of them is the main Web App and the other one is a bridge to communication between other services and my Web App. for communication I am using Web API to transport data from incoming services to the Web App.

Below is my code that transport data:

```
                var client = new RestClient(url);
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("userId", userId);
                request.AddHeader("sign", SignDataExtension.CreateSign(signKey, string.Join("*", strSign)));
                request.AddHeader("json", json.Base64Encode());
                response = client.Execute(request);
```

the `url` is the local address. something like `https://192.168.1.10/api/~`.
The main Web App is configured to redirect any HTTP to HTTPS using `rewrite` in web config.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="asnaf" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

So here is the problem: When I disable redirect to HTTPS, the data is being transferred, but with HTTPS is on, I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

How can I fix this problem?